# how can i resolve this error? when actiong emulator .(attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using react-native with redux-saga but this error happens when emulator acting

error: attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

i think this code is problem

(App.js)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Store from './store/configureStore'
    import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
    import {App} from './src/index';

    const Root = () => {
      return (
        <Provider store={Store()}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      );
    };

    export default Root;
```

(configure/configure.js)

```
    import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
    import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
    import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

    import reducer from '../reducers';
    import rootSaga from '../sagas';

    const Store = () => {
      const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
      const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];
      const enhancer = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
        : composeWithDevTools(
          applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
        );
      const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);
      store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
      return store;
    };

    export default Store;
```

i think error occure is beacuse redux-saga stroe.. how can i fix my code?

Comment: Usually you doesn't invoke the store(), it should be <Provider store={store}>, whats the other error when you removed calling the store ? basically store is an object with some functions so you shouldn't invoke it

Comment: if i remove () this error happned C:\Users\nan84\Cookingrn\front\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:179 TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Comment: As in the above code snippet , not able to find this line, but while checking the error instead of accessing store.getState(), try access it from default like this and check 
 store.default.getState() if you are using require as the way importing it

Comment: Just one doubt, const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer); shouldn't it be const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)); ??